# Android Studio Dynamically Changing Images in GridView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview

I have set up a **GridView** Successfully, however I want to be able to change the Images within the the **GridView** dependent upon a variable. For example:

```
int a = 2
if (a == 2){
    Integer[] images = {
        R.drawable.image1
        R.drawable.image3
    }
} else {
    Integer[] images = (
        R.drawable.image2
        R.drawable.image4
    }
}
```

However I can't find a way to do this. The code I am working with at the moment is:

```
    GridView cardList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    cardList.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    cardList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Create.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(215, 215));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    private Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.iamge1, R.drawable.image2
    };
}
```

Comment: What is happening when you use the code you have written?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at the moment it is working fine as I get a two column grid with all the images within the images array, but I want to make it so I can dynamically change the values inside that array. This way I can filter the images in the grid view to only display some.

Comment: How do you want to trigger the changes? Will it be from a button click?

Comment: Yeah, I will eventually add a filter button which will then only add certain images to the GridView, for now I'd be fine with just variables effecting it if that makes it easier to explain, thanks c:

Comment: Alright I posted an answer that will hopefully help get you started!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

The activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    int images[] = {R.drawable.ic_action_name};
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext(),images);
    gridView.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    }
}
```

Your adapter class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int images[];
Context context;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, int images[]){

    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
}

private class Holder{
    ImageView imageView;
}

@Override
public int getCount(){
    return images.length;
}

@Override public Object getItem(int position){
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position){
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    //All of this Holder stuff is so that the View doesn't jump around wildly

    final Holder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    if (view == null){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.singleimage,null);
        holder = new Holder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.singleImage);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (Holder) view.getTag();}

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    return view;

}
}
```

You also need a simple xml file for the single image in the gridView. Name this "singleimage.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/singleImage"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Activity xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ri.emily.testapp.MainActivity">    

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but where does the first bit of code go, "int a = 2....", in the onCreate part of the activity class? And also do I create a separate XML file for the last part with the ImageView? (Sorry I'm new) @EmilyHommerding

Comment: Yes, it would go in onCreate. You will eventually want to add it to an onClickListener and then notify your adapter of any changes. And yes, a separate XML file for the imageView. Think of it as a generic imageView that gets re-used for all the separate images in the gridView.

Comment: "Can't resolve symbol 'Holder'." is happening everywhere where Hodler is used @Emily Hommerding

Comment: You made the adapter a separate class, right? I added a layoutInflater and clarified the xml file. See if that helps.

Comment: Thank you! This has fixed my ImageAdapter class, however I am still getting these errors in my activity class: http://imgur.com/a/t6ZOi @EmilyHommerding

Comment: The picture is super helpful! You have the capitalization wrong in setAdapter :) It should be setAdapter(imageAdapter). You want the lowercase "i" since that is the actual object. Also, instead of passing "this", try passing getApplicationContext().

Comment: The capitalisation fixed that issue however changing to getApplicationContext() didn't work either, same error as in picture

Comment: Ah, instead of "Integer images[ ]" use "int images [ ]". Changing my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Still same error as in image but this time with "int[]" instead of "java.Lang.Integer[]"

Comment: I edited my answer with an exact copy of what I have working on my machine. Try to see if that works and then we can make the images[ ] process more complex.

Comment: Created another file with just the gridView exactly the same as yours